Why doesn't Prettier configuration sort the imports correctly?
I have this Prettier configuration:
module.exports = {
  plugins: ["@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports"],
  importOrder: [
    "@las/(.*)$",
    "<THIRD_PARTY_MODULES>",
    "^src/(.*)$",
    "@/.*",
    "^[./](?!.*\\.(css|scss)$)", // Relative imports (excluding CSS/SCSS)
    "^(.*\\.(css|scss))$",
  ],
  importOrderSeparation: true,
  importOrderSortSpecifiers: true,
  importOrderParserPlugins: ["typescript", "jsx", "decorators-legacy"],
};


This code sorts the imports correctly except the SCSS/CSS files. It puts them together with the imports from the same folder.
For example:
import axios from "axios";

import "./App.css";
import AudioUse from "./components/AudioUse";
import FileUse from "./components/FileUse";
import GifUse from "./components/GifUse";
import ImageUse from "./components/ImageUse";
import MultipleFilesUse from "./components/MultipleFilesUse";
import VideoUse from "./components/VideoUse";

Why does it happen?
I tried writing this instead:
module.exports = {
    plugins: ["@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports"],
    importOrder: [
      "@las/(.*)$",
      "<THIRD_PARTY_MODULES>",
      "^src/(.*)$",
      "@/.*",
      "^[./]",
      ".*\\.s?css",
    ],
    importOrderSeparation: true,
    importOrderSortSpecifiers: true,
    importOrderParserPlugins: ["typescript", "jsx", "decorators-legacy"],
  };

It still didn't work.
